# Magento Blank Frontend Page and Blank Backend Page after login

Tags: migration

I am moving my local Magento installation **(on OSX)** to the a new server **(opensuse 11.4)**.

- I moved the whole folder with **Magento (Version 1.8.1.0 with the mt_colinus theme installed)**, deleted the `var/cache` and `var/log` folder.
- I exported my local db via `phpMyAdmin` and imported it via `phpMyAdmin` on the server.
- I modified the `app/atc/local.xml` file with the new server mysql data.

**However I get a blank page going to the frontend index.php page.**

The backend `index.php/admin` login page seems to be fine but after submitting the login data I got another blank page `index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/.`

After enabling:

```
ini_set(’display_errors’, 1); 
ini_set(‘memory_limit’, ’256M’);
```

I got this error in the frontend page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /srv/www/htdocs/XXXXXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php on
>   line 67

And this one in the backend dashboard page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addCreateAtPeriodFilter() on a
>   non-object in
>   /srv/www/htdocs/XXXXXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php
>   on line 53

I also uploaded a blank Magento 1.8.1.0 folder without setting the `local.xml` file with the db info (hoping to see the installation wizard) and I still get a blank page. The error in this case is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rewrite() on a non-object in
>   /srv/www/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
>   on line 165

What can I additionally try to do to solve the this issue?

Comment: Check permissions on the var directory. Also, I've seen errors similar to those when Magento cannot connect to the database. Check that your DB user has the correct privileges or temporarily change it to root to rule that out.

Comment: Line numbers change between releases. Either post the relevant line and some context or post your Magento version and make sure the files are pristine (no core hacks).

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post. My magento version is 1.8.1.0 and I didn't changed any core file. My var folder permissions are set to 777 and I was already logging in the DB as root.

Comment: Do you have any apc/memcache/opcache? try to restart php/apache service.

Comment: The blank magento, is that a fresh install, clean database? If so, this is not a magento issue, but a server problem. Do you have symlinks working in your apache installation?

Comment: I ended up creating a new server and downloading again Magento 1.8.1.0 and now it is working fine. Thank you all for the support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, based on the comments, it seams to have gone away on its own.